# "Устанавливали правила, но не добавляли к ним никаких догм"?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Так, воинам, осквернённым убийствами, невозможно было войти в мирный город. Для того и строились многочисленные триумфальные арки, через которые проходили процессии победителей и побеждённых: таким образом люди возвращались  к обычной жизни, где нет места насилию. И пусть воображению римлян не хватало полета, но, глубоко уважая гражданскую власть, они знали точно: закон способен регулировать только человеческие действия, не мысли. Эти талантливые воины, политики и деловые люди прилагали свой практический, здравый смысл и к религии – устанавливали правила, **но не добавляли к ним никаких догм**.*

Слово "догма" - на месте? Правила без добавления догм?

> Догма или Догмат — основное положение какого-либо учения, принимаемое
>   в рамках данного учения истинным, без требования доказательства.

Comment: Пусть автор **пример** подразумеваемого им начальственного подхода к религии приведёт, а то у читателя возникнет примерно такой воспрос: они что, призывали в церковь ходить, но не поститься? Или это о дохристианских временах и они разрешали не приносить в жертву себя Марсу или козу какому-то другому богу? В наше время (и место) можно было бы так себе это представить: рождественский обед в казарме - да, а траву по этому случаю - не красим!

Comment: "Закон способен регулировать только человеческие действия, не мысли." Положение спорное. Например, закон отличает преднамеренное убийство от случайного. Что накое намерение, если не мысль? А что такое инакомыслие, за которое преследуют со средних веков до наших дней? И где это воины, политики и деловые люди устанавливали религиозные правила?

Comment: Правила и догмы - понятия разного толка. Правила могут обосновываться какой-то теорией или догмой, но вряд ли можно говорить о *добавлении* одного к другому.

Comment: Alex_ander, да, времена дохристианские.

Comment: М_Г, ВСЁ - до н. э. Как догму грамотно поженить с правилом?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, автор хотел сказать"устанавливали правила, но не **превращали** их в догмы"?  Правила ведь тоже положения, в которых отражены закономерности. Римляне устанавливали правила - что и как делать, но не превращали их в догмы, не объясняли  необходимость их соблюдения  религией.

Answer (score 1):

**ДОГМА**, [от греч. dógma – мнение, постановление, учение] 1. Положение, принимаемое за непреложную истину, неизменную при всех обстоятельствах. Схоластические догмы. 2. обычно мн.: догмы, догм. Основные положения какого-л. учения. Догмы римского права. Церковные догмы.

Эти талантливые воины, политики и деловые люди прилагали свой практический, здравый смысл и к религии – устанавливали правила **(для действий, связанных с религиозной темой),**  но не добавляли к ним никаких догм **(поясняющих религиозных идей).**

**Проходим через арку – это правило, для чего проходим – в законе не написано.**